# Problem installing hadoop-2.9.1 and jdk1.8.0.111

Tags: hadoop

### I have installed hadoop-2.9.1 and java 8

```
 INFO:  map 0% reduce 0%  .. then Failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1580795821532_0006_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1 .... Exception message: '/tmp/hadoop-Zahedur' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\BigData\hadoop-2.9.1\sbin>hadoop jar C:\Users\sere\Desktop\zahedcon.jar zahedcon.WordCount /input_dir output_dir
Feb 04, 2020 2:03:39 PM org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy newProxyInstance
INFO: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
Feb 04, 2020 2:03:40 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader uploadResourcesInternal
WARNING: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
Feb 04, 2020 2:03:40 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat listStatus
INFO: Total input files to process : 1
Feb 04, 2020 2:03:41 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter submitJobInternal
INFO: number of splits:1
20/02/04 14:03:41 INFO Configuration.deprecation: yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
Feb 04, 2020 2:03:41 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter printTokens
INFO: Submitting tokens for job: job_1580795821532_0006
Feb 04, 2020 2:03:41 PM org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl submitApplication
INFO: Submitted application application_1580795821532_0006
Feb 04, 2020 2:03:41 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job submit
INFO: The url to track the job: http://ZAHED_ICE_RU:8088/proxy/application_1580795821532_0006/
Feb 04, 2020 2:03:41 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job monitorAndPrintJob
INFO: Running job: job_1580795821532_0006
Feb 04, 2020 2:03:50 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job monitorAndPrintJob
INFO: Job job_1580795821532_0006 running in uber mode : false
Feb 04, 2020 2:03:50 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job monitorAndPrintJob


INFO:  map 0% reduce 0%
Feb 04, 2020 2:03:51 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job monitorAndPrintJob
``    NFO: Job job_1580795821532_0006 failed with state FAILED due to: Application   ``application_1580795821532_0006 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1580795821532_0006_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2020-02-04 14:03:48.712]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1580795821532_0006_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Exception message: '/tmp/hadoop-Zahedur' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


[2020-02-04 14:03:48.713]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.
[2020-02-04 14:03:48.713]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://ZAHED_ICE_RU:8088/cluster/app/application_1580795821532_0006 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
Feb 04, 2020 2:03:51 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job monitorAndPrintJob
INFO: Counters: 0
```

Please Help me out ... here are my other files below..

```xml
Mapred-site.xml 
      <configuration>
           <property>
                <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
       <value>yarn</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address </name>
<value>localhost:10020</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
<value>localhost:19888</value>
   </property>

</configuration>
```

```xml
yarn-site.xml
 <configuration>

<property>
         <name>yarn.log.server.url</name>
         <value>http://localhost:19888/jobhistory/logs</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.server.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>localhost:8020</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.server.resourcemanager.application.expiry.interval</name>
    <value>60000</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.server.nodemanager.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:45454</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.server.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
    <value>/app-logs</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
    <value>/C:/BigData/hadoop-2.9.1/logs/userlogs</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.server.mapreduce-appmanager.attempt-listener.bindAddress</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.server.mapreduce-appmanager.client-service.bindAddress</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds</name>
    <value>-1</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
    <value>%HADOOP_CONF_DIR%,%HADOOP_COMMON_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/*,%HADOOP_COMMON_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/lib/*,%HADOOP_HDFS_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/*,%HADOOP_HDFS_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*,%HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,%HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*,%HADOOP_YARN_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/*,%HADOOP_YARN_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

```xml
core-site.xml

<configuration>

 <property>
     <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
     <value>hdfs://localhost:19000</value>
   </property> 
</configuration>`
```

```xml
hdfs-site.xml
`<property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
      <value>/C:/BigData/hadoop-2.9.1/data/namenode</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
      <value>/C:/BigData/hadoop-2.9.1/data/datanode</value>
   </property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for including code in your answer. However, it's best to limit your code to only what seems most relevant.

Comment: Your error message says "For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://ZAHED_ICE_RU:8088/cluster/app/application_1580795821532_0006 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.", did you do this? What do you learn from these logs?

Comment: "Exception message: '/tmp/hadoop-Zahedur' is not recognized as an internal or external command" - can you find anywhere in your codebase that is calling this file?

Comment: Following the link ZAHED_ICE_RU:8088/cluster/app/application_1580795821532_0006 I have got the a page. then click on the logs .....then it shows "unable to connect"

Comment: I don't know "/tmp/hadoop-Zahedur/" where it is located in the codes...

Comment: LOGS: Failed redirect for container_1580787054929_0001_01_000001

 Failed while trying to construct the redirect url to the log server. Log Server url may not be configured
java.lang.Exception: Unknown container. Container either has not started or has already completed or doesn't belong to this node at all.

Comment: Right, you need to view the logs while the server is running.

Comment: 1. Try to provide code of zahedcon.WordCount also verify if /tmp/hadoop-Zahedur/ is used inside your jar file class.
2. There is a WARNING: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this. Also arguments input and output folder should be with correct location.
3. Look if the /tmp folder is present with appropriate permissions. "hadoop-Zahedur" could be application name and job might be trying to create a temp folder like that under /tmp. 
4. Run "hadoop -version" to see if hadoop is installed or not.